# Drag object is behind container

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have 2 containers with one display object in each. When I drag the object from the first container to the second one the object sinks behind the container. setChildIndex seems to work only for the parent container. Is there a way to change the global Z index of a display object?

Comment: You may try depth property on the component.

Comment: There is no reason it should do this unless you told it to. Post some code.